# PHP mysql_connect not returning boolean

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, boolean

I have the following PHP code:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","name","pass") or die(mysql_error());

$db = "db";

mysql_select_db($db,$con);
```

Now in my experience, `$con` should be true or false. When I `echo $con` I get:

```
Resource id #25
```

If I do the following code, the echo never fires (as to be expected after the above statement):

```
if($con) { echo "it worked"; }
```

When I run a query against this connection, everything works as expected. Is there a reason why this `$con` will not be true or false?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: [`Returns a MySQL link identifier on success or FALSE on failure. `](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). Also, judging by the **big red warning box** on mysql_connect's docs you should probably use mysqli or pdo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) Return Values :

```
Returns a MySQL link identifier on success or FALSE on failure.
```

So to check the connection:

```
if($con !== false) { echo "it worked"; }
```

or to quit in case of an error:

```
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

A word of advice though, better to use the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead of `mysql_connect`since it will soon be deprecated:

> **Warning**
>
> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> mysqli_connect()
>
> PDO::__construct()

Answer (score 0):

Its simply b/c of the or `or die(mysql_error());` at the end.

Give this a shot:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","name","pass");
$db = "db";
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db($db,$con);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it is because of the `or die(mysql_error());` part. I should be the `$con = mysql_connect("localhost","name","pass")` only. Then you can check like this: `if (!$con)`.

Comment: @tereško, why the -1 for linking to w3schools, if I may ask?